# `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address` when trying to `git push` on GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

Trying to make a GitHub action to

1. Fork a repo
2. Branch it
3. Make a change
4. Push the change to origin

Problem is that when I get to step 4—I get

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

I have an idea on *why* this is happening—I think git
is trying to prompt interactively for authentication.
I know one solution
is to change the remote origin URL to include the GitHub token like

```
$ git push https://<GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN>@github.com/<GITHUB_USERNAME>/<REPOSITORY_NAME>.git origin <BRANCH_NAME>
```

But then:

1. I have to do some manipulation and modification to the origin url, or hardcode the URL itself, which I'm trying to avoid (if possible) and use the origin url assigned from running `gh repo fork`
2. My GitHub token will be visible in plaintext

Is there a way to pass the token non-interactively to git first to authenticate it for the push?

```yaml
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      manual_release:
        description: "Manually trigger doc build and release."
        required: false
        default: false

jobs:
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    permissions: write-all
      - name: Setup git
        id: setup-git
        if: ${{ steps.setup-pandoc.conclusion == 'success' }}
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "cookiecutter-dash-docset"
          git config --global user.email "cookiecutter.dash.docset@users.noreply.github.com"
     
      - name: Fork
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          gh repo fork --clone Kapeli/Dash-User-Contributions

      - name: Branch
        working-directory: ./Dash-User-Contributions
        run: |
          git switch --create=${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_attempt }}

      - name: Make a change
        working-directory: ./Dash-User-Contributions
        run: |
          echo 'change\n' > file.txt

      - name: Commit
        working-directory: ./Dash-User-Contributions
        run: |
          git add --all
          git commit --message="Change!"

      - name: Push
        working-directory: ./Dash-User-Contributions
        run: |
          git push --set-upstream origin ${{ github.run_id }}-${{ github.run_attempt }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [`GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) is limited to the repository you are running the workflow in, you would not be able to use it to write to another of your repository.

> My GitHub token will be visible in plaintext

Not if you are using a secret, the logs should not display a secret value in plaintext

```yaml
git remote set-url origin https://x-access-token:${{ secrets.MY_TOKEN}}@github.com/${GH_USERNAME/Dash-User-Contributions
```

However, as mentioned in "[Security hardening for GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions)"

> Warning: Any user with write access to your repository has read access to all secrets configured in your repository. Therefore, you should ensure that the credentials being used within workflows have the least privileges required.

So make sure to use a [token made just for the target repository](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens/) (if you know the target repository). Problem, there is [no API to create tokens](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/2531#issuecomment-1098328569).